# php как передать в файл переменные

Tags: php

Есть файл index.php , в нем много процессов и инклудов. Но в нем назначаются и подключаются экземпляры классов. И есть файл на папке /admin/edit/post.php(на него отправляются пост запросы). Как можно передать в этот файл пост назначенные классы из index.php при этом не инклюдя весь index.php, потому как будут запускаться ненужные процессы?

Answer (score 2):

Вынести из `index.php` все определения классов в отдельные файлы (один класс – один файл). Инклюдить их и в `index.php` и, нужные, в `post.php`.

А по-хорошему, разобраться с [автозагрузкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/.  Composer: https://getcomposer.org/